# Expand cards and autosize figures in Dash Python

Tags: python, data-science, plotly-dash

My dashboard is composed of cards that inside have a header with text and a button that I want to use to expand these cards, in the body is a figure for each card.

[image]

I want to ask if there is a way to press the header button and the card opens or expands and the graphics inside change their size automatically.

Best regards.